# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() | Laravel v8.14

Tags: php, laravel, components, laravel-blade, laravel-8

okay, just now I just got an error on *resources/view/components/auth/**select-angkatan*** when I wanted to get data from *App/view/components/auth/**SelectAngkatan***.

So you see, I just created the **select-angkatan** component in *resource/view/components/auth* and I try to get data **Angkatan** model from *App/view/components/auth/**SelectAngkatan***. and I get an error Invalid argument supplied for foreach() and undefined variable $angkatan in **select-angkatan.blade.php** in line 8. can anybody help me, please

> *resources/view/components/auth/**select-angkatan.blade.php***

```
@props(['field', 'label'])
<div class="formel form-regis">
  <div class="select">
      <label for="{{ $field }}">{{ $label ?? '' }}</label>
      <select name="{{ $field }}" id="{{ $field }}" value="{{ old($field) }}">
          <option selected disabled>-</option>
       {{----  Error  ----}}
          @foreach ($angkatan as $data)
              <option value="{{ $data->id }}">{{ $data->angkatan }}</option>
          @endforeach
      </select>
  </div>
  @error($field)
      <span>
          <strong> {{ $message }} </strong>
      </span>
  @enderror
</div>
```

> *App/View/Components/auth/**SelectAngkatan.php***

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components\auth;

use App\Models\Angkatan;
use Illuminate\View\Component;

class SelectAngkatan extends Component
{
    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        $angkatan = Angkatan::all();
        return view('components.auth.select-angkatan', compact('angkatan'));
    }
}
```

> *App/Models/**Angkatan.php***

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Angkatan extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried dumping the problematic variable to see what it actually contains?

Comment: can you dd this variable $angkatan dd($angkatan); in view file and show output actual output comming ?

Comment: yes I have. and the result is the same error, undefined variable angkatan on select-angkatan.blade.php

Comment: `
{{----  Error  ----}}
@foreach ($angkatan as $data)
{{ dd($angkatan) }}
       <option value="{{ $data->id }}">{{ $data->angkatan }}</option>
@endforeach
`

Comment: so inside your render(), does $angkatan contain any value?

Comment: @AngelDeykov it should be, but still undefined variable $angkatan on resource/components/auth/**select-angkatan.blade.php**

Comment: it should be??? Just check it, right after $angkatan = Angkatan::all();var_dump($angkatan);die; Is there anything inside? Also do you get the same errors if you try to return the data without the PHP compact()- return view('components.auth.select-angkatan', ['angkatan' => $angkatan]); ?

Comment: yes in the $angkatan is contains a value. I've done try both with PHP compact or without compact and yes the same error @AngelDeykov

Comment: Try delete all views in cache.

Comment: Can you also post your Illuminate\View\Component class?